# print count variable from another class

Tags: java, class, variables, printing

I created a RandomSumGame in Java and need to provide a count of the amount of wins and losses.  I tried to add the print out of the count within the method but it printed it out after each game instead of one total at the end.  I moved the print to the main class but I cannot get it to print the count total from the other class.
Below is my program

```
package Question4;

import java.util.Random;

public class RandomSumGame {

    boolean start;
    int d1;
    int d2;
    int sum = d1 + d2;
    int valuePoint;
    String status = "+";
        
    public void play (int d1, int d2) {
        sum = d1 + d2;
        int countW = 0;
        int countL = 0;
        for (;;) { //Part I. of question
            if (sum == 2 || sum == 3 || sum == 12) {
                start = false;
                System.out.println(" = " + sum + "\nCRAPS! You lose!");
                countL++;
                break;
            }
            else if (sum == 7 || sum == 11) { //Part II. of question
                start = true;
                System.out.println(" = " + sum + "\nNATURAL! You win!");
                countW++;
                break;
            }
            
            valuePoint = sum;
            
            if (valuePoint == 4 ||valuePoint == 5 || valuePoint == 6 || valuePoint == 8 
                    || valuePoint == 9 || valuePoint == 10) { //Part III. of question
                System.out.println(" = " + valuePoint + "\nA value point of " + valuePoint 
                                        + " has been established. Roll again.");
                break;
            }
        }
        
        for (;;) {
            if (sum == 7) { //exception to valuepoint is 7
                break;
            }
            else {
                Random rand = new Random();
                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                    d1 = 1 + rand.nextInt(6);
                    int a1 = d1;
                    System.out.print("You rolled\n" + "\t" + d1);
                    
                    for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++) {
                        d2 = 1 + rand.nextInt(6);
                        int a2 = d2;
                        int sum = a1 + a2;
                        System.out.println(" " + status + " " + d2 + " = " + sum);  
                    }   
                }
                
                sum = d1 + d2;
                
                if (sum == valuePoint) { //if sum equals valuepoint established
                    start = true;
                    System.out.print("\t" + "You win!" + "\n");
                    countW++;
                    break;
                }
                
                else if (sum == 7) {
                    start = false;
                    System.out.print("\t" + "You lose! " + "\n");
                    countL++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void play () {
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
        rolldice();
        play(d1, d2);
        System.out.print("\n");
        }  
    }

    public void rolldice() {
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            d1 = 1 + rand.nextInt(6);
            System.out.print("You rolled " + d1 + " " + status);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            d2 = 1 + rand.nextInt(6);
            System.out.print(" " + d2 + " ");
        }   
    }
    
}//end of class
```

and this is my main

```
package Question4;

public class TestRandomSumGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        
        System.out.println("Craps is a dice game where two dice are rolled."
                + " The dice are added together and; \nIf the sum is 7 or 11, you win!"
                + "\nIf the sum is 2, 3, or 12, you lose!"
                + "\nIf the sum is 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, or 10, a valuepoint is established which is"
                + "\nwhere you contine to roll the dice until you roll the same number"
                + " (you win)"
                + "\nor a 7 (you lose)."
                + "\nThe game will run for 3 plays.\n");
        
            RandomSumGame test = new RandomSumGame();
            
            test.play();
            
            
            System.out.println("Wins: " + countW + "\nLosses: " + countL);
            
    }
    
}//end of class
```

I am sure I am missing something easy but I just cannot seem to fix this problem.

Comment: Aren't you missing `test` here? `System.out.println("Wins: " + test.countW + "\nLosses: " + test.countL);`. That considering that those properties are public.

Answer (score 0):

define countW and countL as global variables as you're using them as local variables only available inside play() method. So instead of this

```
public void play (int d1, int d2) {
    int countW = 0;
    int countL = 0;
```

use something like this

```
int countW = 0;
int countL = 0;
public void play (int d1, int d2) {
```

and call those variables using the object

```
    System.out.println("Wins: " + test.countW + "\nLosses: " + test.countL);
```

---

Also I'd suggest that you use Encapsulation ( Getters and Setters )
for your example you define the variables as private and write a getter method to access it f.e

```
private int countL = 0;
public void getCountL(){
    return this.countL;
}
```

and to call it use
`test.getCountL();`

Comment: Thank you I made the variables global.  I knew it was something little I was missing.

Comment: @ekelly glad it helped, mark this as answers would help me too :D thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have named 2 function 'play'.
But after that you can simply define this play function that you are using in the main function as an return funnction with type of int array.
Fixed code.

Main

```
public class TestRandomSumGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        
        System.out.println("Craps is a dice game where two dice are rolled."
                + " The dice are added together and; \nIf the sum is 7 or 11, you win!"
                + "\nIf the sum is 2, 3, or 12, you lose!"
                + "\nIf the sum is 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, or 10, a valuepoint is established which is"
                + "\nwhere you contine to roll the dice until you roll the same number"
                + " (you win)"
                + "\nor a 7 (you lose)."
                + "\nThe game will run for 3 plays.\n");
        
            RandomSumGame test = new RandomSumGame();
            
            int[] outcome = test.play();
            
            
            System.out.println("Wins: " + outcome[0] + "\nLosses: " + outcome[1]);
            
    }
```

Your class

```
package Question4;

import java.util.Random;

public class RandomSumGame {

    boolean start;
    int d1;
    int d2;
    int sum = d1 + d2;
    int valuePoint;
    String status = "+";
        
    public int[] start_game (int d1, int d2) {
        sum = d1 + d2;
        int countW = 0;
        int countL = 0;
        for (;;) { //Part I. of question
            if (sum == 2 || sum == 3 || sum == 12) {
                start = false;
                System.out.println(" = " + sum + "\nCRAPS! You lose!");
                countL++;
                break;
            }
            else if (sum == 7 || sum == 11) { //Part II. of question
                start = true;
                System.out.println(" = " + sum + "\nNATURAL! You win!");
                countW++;
                break;
            }
            
            valuePoint = sum;
            
            if (valuePoint == 4 ||valuePoint == 5 || valuePoint == 6 || valuePoint == 8 
                    || valuePoint == 9 || valuePoint == 10) { //Part III. of question
                System.out.println(" = " + valuePoint + "\nA value point of " + valuePoint 
                                        + " has been established. Roll again.");
                break;
            }
        }
        
        for (;;) {
            if (sum == 7) { //exception to valuepoint is 7
                break;
            }
            else {
                Random rand = new Random();
                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                    d1 = 1 + rand.nextInt(6);
                    int a1 = d1;
                    System.out.print("You rolled\n" + "\t" + d1);
                    
                    for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++) {
                        d2 = 1 + rand.nextInt(6);
                        int a2 = d2;
                        int sum = a1 + a2;
                        System.out.println(" " + status + " " + d2 + " = " + sum);  
                    }   
                }
                
                sum = d1 + d2;
                
                if (sum == valuePoint) { //if sum equals valuepoint established
                    start = true;
                    System.out.print("\t" + "You win!" + "\n");
                    countW++;
                    break;
                }
                
                else if (sum == 7) {
                    start = false;
                    System.out.print("\t" + "You lose! " + "\n");
                    countL++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
       int[] outcome = {countW, countL}
       return outcome
    }
    
    public int[] play () {
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
        rolldice();
        int[] outcome = start_game(d1, d2);
        System.out.print("\n");
        }
        return outcome
    }

    public void rolldice() {
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            d1 = 1 + rand.nextInt(6);
            System.out.print("You rolled " + d1 + " " + status);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            d2 = 1 + rand.nextInt(6);
            System.out.print(" " + d2 + " ");
        }   
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this is an assignment and the parameters are provided to me.

Answer (score 0):

I would take some time out from this project to read some about how to do object-oriented programming. Anything by Alan Kay or Allen Holub is a good start, although there are many others just as lucid. Please don't pay attention to the advice about getters and setters having anything to do with encapsulation. They leak internal details too. True, they are marginally better than public fields, but you want to try to avoid giving state out entirely. As you get good at OO programming you'll find you can avoid getters and setters (and god forbid any kind of exposed field) more than 90% of the time. The result is that your code is better, faster, more decoupled, easier to maintain, etc. For a quick article, read this:

https://www.infoworld.com/article/2073723/why-getter-and-setter-methods-are-evil.html

If you don't have time for the article, the most important thing to know about OO programming from that article is basically this:

```
It's not about objects, it's about conversations, and in those converstations you don't ask an object for its state to do some work, you ask the object with the state to do the work for you.
```

Alan Kay said that he thought he'd made a mistake calling it object-oriented programming. It would have been better if it had been called message-oriented programming. I agree.

In passing, James Gosling was asked what he considered his biggest mistake in Java. He said "classes". It took me quite a bit longer to understand the details of that statement, but I eventually realized he was both being deliberately funny and that he was dead right.

Jon

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: You're welcome. If you actually go and do this, I may have saved you years in your career advancement. Such a small number of people really go and do this.